# Sort qualitative variable with groups and keeping the indexes

Tags: r, sorting

I have a variable composed by 6 different letters, I need to sort this obtaining 6 different indexes, so that I will be able to sort a dataset according to this qualitative variable.

here's the variable:

```
data =   c("H", "H", "A", "A", "B", "R", "E", "B", "E", "B", "A", "E", 
    "R", "R", "I", "B", "I", "I", "H", "A", "E", "I", "B", "I", "H", 
    "B", "R", "E", "B", "R", "H", "R", "I", "A", "B", "E", "A", "E", 
    "I", "H", "A", "E", "I", "H", "R", "H", "A", "R")
```

if I sort this I'm obtaining only the alphabetic order:

```
data_idx = sort(data, index.return = TRUE)
```

- How can I obtain these indexes and reorder this variable?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is. Could you explain further what you mean by "sort a dataset according to this qualitative variable?"

Comment: I would like to obtain 6 different indexes, one index for each group: like which(data == "A"), which(data == "B"), which(data == "E")... and so on, how can I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract with either `$` or `[[` as it is a `list` output when we use `index.return = TRUE`

```
sort(data, index.return = TRUE)$ix
```

---

Another option is `order`

```
order(data)
```

---

If we need to obtain index

```
match(data, unique(data))
```

Or may be

```
split(seq_along(data), data)
```

Or with `ave`

```
ave(seq_along(data), data, FUN = seq_along)
```

Comment: I would like to obtain 6 different indexes, one index for each group: like which(data == "A"), which(data == "B"), which(data == "E")... and so on, how can I perform this?

Comment: split is awesome!